# catching a GenericJDBCException

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

I have a form page and when i save it, it overwrites to the database.  Within the form page is a text box that allows the user to enter 4000 characters but if the user enters more than this i get the following error:

> ```
>  ERROR 15:54:05 AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(301) |
>  Could not synchronize database state with session
>  org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
> ```

I know it is because it is trying to add more than the database will allow. I just want to catch the exception and redirect back to the form page.

It is failing when the controller passes it to the handle request on this line:

```
return super.handleRequest(request,response);
```

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: have you tried using `try` and `catch(GenericJDBCException e)` ?

Comment: Just restrict on client side not to enter more than 4000 characters and in your controller check if that text contains >4000 characters?

Comment: Also, it is better to do what Pradeep mentions, this is cleaner

Comment: Yeah i had it this way and then had to change it to handle when the user puts in too much text.  Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    /* your code that creates the exception */
} catch (GenericJDBCException e) {
    /* redirect back to form page */
}
```

Comment: Brilliant i had the try and catch in the wrong area of the code.  Thanks !